# Using Rake gem, no rakefile found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm trying to build a custom version of Zepto.js with the optional data module. I'm a bit new to using terminal commands, so when things don't work I'm generally unsure what to do!

I'm on a Mac and have installed Ruby 1.9.3p385. When installing the Rake gem using 'gem install rake', it seems to install fine. However, using the 'rake' command throws this error:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/Users/matthew_ruddy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/matthew_ruddy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm not what to do from here. I also can't get the 'bundle' gem to work, it throws the following error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Clueless where to go from here. Here is the list of gems installed I get when I run 'gem list'.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.2.4)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
```

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you're in the wrong directory.

You need to change to the right directory using the "cd" command.  You can figure out what directory you're in using the "pwd" command.

Here are the steps I used to install on my computer:

1. checkout the repository into /tmp/zepto

   ```
   dan@computer:/home$ cd /tmp
   dan@computer:/tmp$ git clone 
   dan@computer:/tmp$ git clone git@github.com:madrobby/zepto.git
   Cloning into 'zepto'...
   remote: Counting objects: 5721, done.
   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1962/1962), done.
   remote: Total 5721 (delta 3937), reused 5333 (delta 3602)
   Receiving objects: 100% (5721/5721), 6.11 MiB | 475 KiB/s, done.
   Resolving deltas: 100% (3937/3937), done.
   ```
2. change to the /tmp/zepto directory

   ```
   dan@computer:/tmp$ cd zepto/
   dan@computer:/tmp/zepto (master)$ pwd
   /tmp/zepto
   ```
3. Install the gems with bundler

   ```
   dan@computer:/tmp/zepto (master)$ bundle
   Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/....
   Fetching https://github.com/lautis/uglifier
   remote: Counting objects: 750, done.
   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (386/386), done.
   remote: Total 750 (delta 381), reused 670 (delta 304)
   Receiving objects: 100% (750/750), 278.16 KiB | 283 KiB/s, done.
   Resolving deltas: 100% (381/381), done.
   Installing rake (0.9.2.2) 
   Installing multi_json (1.6.1) 
   Installing execjs (1.4.0) 
   Using uglifier (1.3.0) from https://github.com/lautis/uglifier (at master) 
   Using bundler (1.2.3) 
   Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
   ```
4. Build zepto with rake

   ```
   dan@computer:/tmp/zepto (master)$ bundle exec rake
   Original version: 54.021k
   Minified: 24.897k
   Minified and gzipped: 9.258k, compression factor 5.835
   ```
5. Check that the zepto.js file has been built

   ```
   dan@computer:/tmp/zepto (master)$ ls -l dist/
   total 124
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 daniel daniel 55317 Feb 23 23:32 zepto.js
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 daniel daniel 25495 Feb 23 23:32 zepto.min.js
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 daniel daniel 38097 Feb 23 23:32 zepto.min.js.map.json
   ```